# Execute Apple Push Notification Server (PHP) from Android Device using "PHP for Android"

Tags: php, android, ssl, apple-push-notifications, sl4a

I recently downloaded and installed "PHP for Android." I created a .php file that utilizes an SSL connection with port 2195. I followed a guide for writing a php server that sends push notifications to Apple's APNS, and SUCCESSfully ran it on my Mac. When I put both the .php and the .pem onto my Android phone in the same folder and tried to run it with the same WIFI connection, I get the following error message:

```
Error:14094410:SSL routines:func(148):reason(1040) in /mnt/sdcard/sl4a/scripts/lot.php on line 19

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /mnt/sdcard/sl4a/scripts/lot.php on line 19

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /mnt/sdcard/sl4a/scripts/lot.php on line 19
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can fix this?
THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the SSL error on my Windows desktop, with a PHP script that accessed a HTTPS resource.

The solution was to enable the openssl extension. So maybe it's the same kind of problem you have here, something related to opensll on Php for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix it, but Google has it's own push notification framework. There is an example here: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Edit to Answer:

I think that most likely the problem has to do with the certificates needed to make the call over SSL. It is possible that the PHP for Android app does not have permissions to access security certificates you need.

Comment: To Clarify, the php sends the push notifications to Apple's push notification service for registered iPhones.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes much more sense.

Comment: hmm...that could be a possibility. Might you know how I can get around that problem?

I've tried putting the certificate on my website and trying to call it from there, but that didn't seem to work...maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: I have not done much work with PHP or client-side SSL, but you might try adding your code to the question. You will likely get more answers.